# Parent() of parent of parent

Tags: jquery

I have this ul tree list.

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">
                  <li  class="sub-menu">
                      <a href="file0.asp">
                          <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                          <span>Dashboard</span>
                      </a>
                  <ul class="sub">
                      <li><a  href="file.html">Pricefile</a></li>
                      <li><a href="file2.html">Pricefile</a></li>
                      <li><a  href="file3.html">Pricefile</a></li>
                  </ul>

                  </li>
              </ul>
```

i have this script to locate the current page, and set add the current li class to .active. So far so good.

but i also need to set class on my .. to class .active.
How can i do that, with the parent function?

```
var str=location.href.toLowerCase();
    $("#sidebar li a").each(function() {
    if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1) {    
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    $(this).parent().parent().parent('a').addClass("active"); // THIS LINE
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it right, just `parent()` up the dom tree.

However, instead of using `parent().parent().parent().parent()` etc may I suggest using `closest()` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)) which will search up the dom tree for the matching element. For instance

```
$('li.active').closest('ul').addClass('active');
```

Edit:

If you are trying to get something inside an element, you can use `find()`. It might be something like:

```
$('li.active').find('a').addClass('active');
```

#### Edit:

Ah, sorry so you would go:

```
$('li.active').closest('li').find('a:first-child').addClass('active');
```

Or

```
$(this).closest('.sub-menu').find('a:first-child').addClass('active');
```

Comment: UNclear question but looks like OP wants to add active class to anchor element, not UL

Comment: Sorry, i want to add .active on  this 
<a class="active" href="file0.asp">
                          <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                          <span>Dashboard</span>
                      </a>

Comment: @KevinLund Hey Kevin, sorry only just saw this and edited my answer.